# Wordpress Multiple Search Box

Tags: wordpress, search

WordPress How to filtering with multiple search box?

3 search box and a button. Each box is available for a taxonomy. When the button is clicked to do the filtering.

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

See if any of these plugins can help you -

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-advanced-search

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advance-wp-query-search-filter

https://pippinsplugins.com/advanced-search-shortcode